# webpage has a redirect loop: chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I am facing a problem whenever I try appearing for a test in gateforum online test series. It used to work properly but now i am facing an issue. The whole account works properly except the one portion, As soon as I try to open tests , it shows an error in chrome saying the webpage has a redirect loop, I cleared all the cookies and cache, reinstalled chrome , still getting it. Also, I tried to use firefox browser, it also shows an error saying cookies might not be enabled , only if particularly tests button it clicked. Just to mention I checked for the cookies in firefox, there is no issue regarding it and cleared them there also, but not able to solve it. It would be really helpful if anybody could help.

Comment: It looks like the problem is not with your browsers. It will be related with that site. They may have to fix that issue.

Comment: But it works perfectly in another computer. Also, I talked to the technical guy over there , he said there is no issue from their side as it works on other PCs.

Comment: Have you checked your system date? check ur system date...it should be set to current date & time

Comment: @NithinPaul it's correct. 
should I format the pc (only if there is no alternative) ?

Comment: Have you tried:

deactivating all plugins to see if this resolves the problem. If this works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the problematic plugin(s).

Comment: @NithinPaul Just tried, didn't work.

Comment: Oh then what went wrong :(. Others also reported some issues regarding this on google's tech page https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!newtopic/gmail/gmail/_Va_4yGPjx8. But this one is a old bug.

Comment: If there is no alternative found, like you said format your system and then try :(

Comment: ohh ... okay.
thank you for your effort to help anyways .. :)